# Dissolving layer with two or more fields in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis-3, layers, fields-attributes, dissolve

I want to dissolve the layer based on two or more fields through `"Processing modeler"`.

How to set and where to set those fields? When I use `"Dissolve"` tool separately I can choose fields that I want, but not in this case.

I am using QGIS 3.10.

[image: example]
This is my table. I like to dissolve with fields: "SP" and "PJ"
[image]

Comment: Maybe you will find it useful [Filter options are not saving in Dissolve algorithm window through Graphical modeler in QGIS 2](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/313473/filter-options-are-not-saving-in-dissolve-algorithm-window-through-graphical-mod). Mainly what [@Joseph](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/25814/joseph) has suggested

Answer (score 2):

You can set the columns right there in the dialogue, you simply have to know how exactly they are named - and if you want to reuse the model, the columns have to stay the same, or you'd have to alter the model every time.

[image]

Comment: I already tried with my fields, but I don't know how to write. When I write my fields like: state, city, after processing I get one column with those fields together.

Comment: There are no fields in the dropdown list?.

Comment: How should the model know, how the columns of the data, which is to be processed anytime in the future, are called? Please state how exactly you wrote your column names into this field.

Comment: I supplemented the question. I want to dissolve with "SP" and "PJ". I wrote exactly this: sp, pj and nothing happened

Comment: @nagib - Use the `Vector Field` input parameter in your model and connect this to your input layer (enable the _Accept multiple fields_ option). Then in the `Dissolve` tool, connect the dissolve field to the `Vector Field` parameter and away you go.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve the problem. Thank You Joseph.
The problem was with GDAL Dissolve tool. I used QGIS dissolve tool, and everything work fine.
[image]

Comment: Note that it should also work with GDAL's Dissolve tool.

Comment: Not in my case. The result with GDAL is everything is summarised in one field